# AppCenter failed to get module and shows error 65

Tags: ios, xcode, visual-studio-app-center

I am using Swift with CocoaPods and trying to build it in AppCenter.

I kept getting this failing log

```
    CompileSwift normal arm64 (in target 'Wundercast' from project 'Wundercast')
    cd /Users/runner/runners/2.165.2/work/1/s
    /Applications/Xcode_11.3.1.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -emit-bc /Users/runner/runners/2.165.2/work/1/s/Wundercast/ViewController.swift /Users/runner/runners/2.165.2/work/1/s/Wundercast/Utils/Colors.swift /Users/runner/runners/2.165.2/work/1/s/Wundercast/AppDelegate.swift /Users/runner/runners/2.165.2/work/1/s/Wundercast/Controllers/ApiController.swift /Users/runner/runners/2.165.2/work/1/s/Wundercast/Utils/Appearance.swift -supplementary-output-file-map /var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/supplementaryOutputs-8c8267 -target arm64-apple-ios10.1 -Xllvm -aarch64-use-tbi -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode_11.3.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk -I /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Wundercast-ermhkmlzqioflkgqqzuvbqmqczqy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Wundercast/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -F /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/W...
/Users/runner/runners/2.165.2/work/1/s/Wundercast/ViewController.swift:30:8: error: no such module 'RxSwift'
import RxSwift
       ^

** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileSwift normal armv7
    CompileSwiftSources normal armv7 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
    CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
    CompileSwift normal arm64
(4 failures)
##[error]Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 65
```

With previous research, I have configured the project with `xcworkspace`, and `appcenter-post-clone.sh` to install CocoaPods.

[Here is the test project link.](https://github.com/ji3g4kami/appcentertest)

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Make sure your CI job runs `pod install` before starting the compiler.

Comment: @Gereon I've used Microsoft's example: https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/blob/master/sample-build-scripts/ios/match-cocoapods-version-to-lockfile/appcenter-post-clone.sh
but it still doesn't work.

Comment: After building in release mode locally, it seems the problem lies locally with `No such module 'RxSwift'`. Not an AppCenter problem.

Comment: The script you're using only installs cocoapods, but never runs it. Again: make sure `pod install` is executed before you start any compilation, locally and on your CI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few tries with [a blank project](https://github.com/ji3g4kami/CocoaPodsWithCI), it worked pretty well with the following `appcenter-post-clone.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Uninstalling all CocoaPods versions"
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods --all --executables

COCOAPODS_VER=`sed -n -e 's/^COCOAPODS: \([0-9.]*\)/\1/p' Podfile.lock`

echo "Installing CocoaPods version $COCOAPODS_VER"
sudo gem install cocoapods -v $COCOAPODS_VER

cd $APPCENTER_SOURCE_DIRECTORY
pod install
```

However, the original project still fails in the release mode even locally. At least I now know the problem has nothing to do with AppCenter, but rather has some issues with Xcode. By dragging the project files into a new Xcode project, it worked like charm.